# lots of erros while executing step "configure && make && make install"

Tags: gcc, makefile, apache-kafka, configure, netflow

I am trying to install f2k in my ubuntu14 machine by cloning the [git repo](https://github.com/redBorder/f2k) and executing the the step "./configure && make && make install". However, I'm getting lots of "no such header file errors". Please find below the snippet that I got after executing the step. There were other errors too, which I removed by removing some of dependent packages. But, for below errors, I'm not able to find any proper solution.

> root@ubuntu:/home/devops/f2k# ./configure
>   checking for OS or distribution... ok (Ubuntu)
>   checking for C compiler from CC env... failed
>   checking for gcc (by command)... ok
>   checking executable ld... ok
>   checking executable nm... ok
>   checking executable objdump... ok
>   checking executable strip... ok
>   checking for pkgconfig (by command)... ok
>   checking for install (by command)... ok
>   checking for __atomic_32 (by compile)... ok
>   checking for __atomic_64 (by compile)... ok
>   checking for socket (by compile)... ok
>   checking for librd (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for librd (by compile)... failed (fail)
>   checking for pcap (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for pcap (by compile)... failed (fail)
>   checking for librdkafka (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for librdkafka (by compile)... ok
>   checking for rb_mac_vendor (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for rb_mac_vendor (by compile)... failed (fail)
>   checking for geoip (by pkg-config)... ok
>   checking for zookeeper (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for zookeeper (by compile)... ok
>   checking for udns (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for udns (by compile)... failed (fail)
>   checking for HAVE_JSON (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for HAVE_JSON (by compile)... ok
>   checking for optreset (by compile)... failed (disable)
>   checking for pthread (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for pthread (by compile)... ok
>   checking for pthread_setaffinity_np (by compile)... failed (disable)
>   checking for sin6_len (by compile)... failed (disable)
>   checking for netfilter (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for netfilter (by compile)... failed (disable)
>   checking for sctp (by compile)... failed (disable)
>   checking for pcap_next_ex (by compile)... failed (disable)
>   checking for pf_ring (by pkg-config)... failed
>   checking for pf_ring (by compile)... failed (disable)
>    librd ()
>       module: f2k
>       action: fail
>       reason:
>   compile check failed:
>   CC: CC
>   flags: -lrd -lpthread -lz -lrt
>   gcc  -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -Wcast-qual -Wunused -Wextra -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Wswitch-default -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wcast-align -Wdisabled-optimization -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -DFORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -Werror -lrd -lpthread -lz -lrt _mkltmp8AkgWk.c -o _mkltmp8AkgWk.c.o  :
>   _mkltmp8AkgWk.c:1:22: fatal error: librd/rd.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>                         ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   source: #include 
>   pcap ()
>       module: f2k
>       action: fail
>       reason:
>   compile check failed:
>   CC: CC
>   flags: -lpcap
>   gcc  -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -Wcast-qual -Wunused -Wextra -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Wswitch-default -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wcast-align -Wdisabled-optimization -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -DFORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -Werror -lpcap _mkltmpDRRB09.c -o _mkltmpDRRB09.c.o  :
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   source:
>    rb_mac_vendor (HAVE_RB_MAC_VENDORS)
>       module: f2k
>       action: fail
>       reason:
>   compile check failed:
>   CC: CC
>   flags: -lrb_mac_vendors
>   gcc  -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -Wcast-qual -Wunused -Wextra -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Wswitch-default -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wcast-align -Wdisabled-optimization -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -DFORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -Werror -lrb_mac_vendors _mkltmpmtvaLo.c -o _mkltmpmtvaLo.c.o  :
>   _mkltmpmtvaLo.c:1:28: fatal error: rb_mac_vendors.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>   compilation terminated.
>   source: #include 
>   udns (HAVE_UDNS)
>       module: f2k
>       action: fail
>       reason:
>   compile check failed:
>   CC: CC
>   flags: -ludns
>   gcc -I/usr/include/ -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -Wcast-qual -Wunused -Wextra -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Wswitch-default -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wcast-align -Wdisabled-optimization -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -DFORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -Werror -ludns _mkltmpNkVGfP.c -o _mkltmpNkVGfP.c.o  :
>   /tmp/ccA5w4FZ.o: In function `f':
>
>   /home/devops/f2k/_mkltmpNkVGfP.c:2: undefined reference to`dns_init'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   source: #include 
>               void *f();void *f(){return dns_init;}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that author was too optimistic about simple install - you need to install number of libraries to make it working: `librd`, `libpcap`, `rb_mac_vendors` (from the same author), etc.

Comment: I installed these dependencies...but no luck

Comment: last error from the above question which is related to `dns_init`

Comment: yah...I installed it as `sudo apt-get install -y libudns-dev`. I rebooted the instance also....Any other idea?

Comment: No, sorry - don't have any other idea

Comment: did you install libraries that are marked as failed?

Comment: installed most of them..but for some it is still showing failed though installed